# How to get html inside a parent element from data_response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm doing an ajax call, the `data_response` has a single HTML element with a lot of markup inside:

```
<div>**code I want to retrieve**</div>
```

I want to get the innerHtml without the parent element, so that I put it inside another element.

Basically:

```
$('selector').html(**code I want to retrieve**);
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the response really just contains HTML, then you can parse it easily using JQuery:

```
var html = $(data_response).html();
$('selector').html(html);
```

**Edit**

It's the same principle as this:

```
var newElement = $("<div id='foo'>stuff</div>");
$("body").append(newElement);
var theElement = $("#foo");
console.log(theElement.html());
```

> stuff

Comment: You may as well explain how it works. In this case, you're creating a jQuery object containing the parsed `div` element, then using [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) which retrieves the html of the first element inside of that jQuery object.